# Android and dealing with illegal characters in file names

Tags: android

My app can accept various files e.g. images and such but the problem is if the file such as an image contains illegal characters clicking on it will crash the app. How can such behavior be avoided? if possible I'd still like to be able to have the image open. Thanks.

```
    attachedImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            String new_string = imageURI.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
            image_uri = Uri.parse("file://" + new_string);
            intent.setDataAndType(image_uri, "image/*");                
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where did you get the images from? Is it a server? Have you tried to rename the file to replace the illegal characters? What kind of characters are we talking about?

Comment: The images reside on the users sd card so the file names could potentially contain anything.

Comment: That's odd.  Please provide an example of a file name that causes this crash (escaping character codes if they don't come through StackOverflow cleanly), and the specific API call that is crashing.

Comment: Well one filename contains spaces but I got around that with String new_string = imageURI3.replaceAll(" ", "%20"); But here is the debug from the file giving errors I'm testing with...12-14 12:51:43.404: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18175): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 76: file:///mnt/sdcard/Sia%20-%20We%20Are%20Born%20(2010)/Sia-We%20Are%20Born%20[Front].jpg

Comment: Since it's causing an IllegalArgumentException, you could always put the code into a try/catch block and handle the exception that way, but I don't think that's the main problem. A space in a filename shouldn't cause problems, can you post your code that is retrieving the image?

Comment: You need to escape all those characters. This isn't a URL. File path locations don't escape spaces to %20, you escape a space with `\ `. And I'm pretty sure you'll have to escape both  `()` and `[]`.

Comment: I tried adding try/catch block but gallery still opens then force closes

Comment: @Paul did you solve your problem? One of my applications that dealing with files is running fine until the file name contains this character ':'. So now i am aware that some illegal characters can cause my application force closed and i need to get a workaround with this problem.